# Send 404 Header with php, when header already sent (workaround)

Tags: header, http-status-code-404

i have tried to send the 404 header with:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

but it doesn't work.

I think it doesn't work, because the header is sent at the end of the page.

Problem is...

if user request the page mydomain/help
 --> Server shows help

if user verifies the email adresse with mydomain/blub@asdfsi.com
--> server activates the email adress

that means, the decision, if any page can be displayed or not, can only be given at the end of the page, because the possible URIs are not static...

has anyone an idea, how i can send the 404 header after processing / outputting many stuff?

PS: sorry for my bad english ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution (at the beginning):

```
$allowed= array('Start' , 'Main', 'Sub' , 'Presub');

if (!in_array($url, $allowed)) 
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

It works, but in the future, the array could be long and longer and longer...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error, replace the `header(Location: ...)` by following:

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          window.location.href = "PATH TO REDIRECT TO";
      </script>';
```